# How to store value '<?php' in variable in php?

Tags: php

I want to store php script as a variable.
How can I do that?
I tried

```
$template = '<?php';
$template = '<'.'?'.'php'.'\n';
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: The first one is correct. But the problem is how are you using it?

Comment: To get higher quality answers, write a [higher quality question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) by including [sample code](http://sscce.org/) that is complete yet concise, including e.g. HTML source, SQL statements or table defintions, and preferrably some sample input and output data. See also [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [HelpOverflow](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help2)

Comment: "doesn't work" is never a sufficient problem description. Please describe your expected output, and your actual output. Context is important, we need to know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct.
If you try this:

```
<?php
    $template = '<?php';
    echo $template;
    $template = '<'.'?'.'php'.'\n';
    echo $template;
?>
```

you'll end up with an empty HTML page but if you view the source you will find

```
<?php<?php\n
```

as result, and it's rendered by HTML as incorrect tag that's why you have an empty page.

Try this:

```
<?php
    $template = '<?php';
?>
<script language="javascript">
    alert(<?php echo "\"".$template."\""; ?>); 
</script>
```

and you'll end up with the correct value shown in javascript alert popup

Comment: omg! I thought it was because of php's interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually nothing wrong with your first usage. PHP is not like JavaScript that prohibits you to use `<script>` inside it. The following will output the `<?php` tag correctly:

```
<?php

$template = '<?php';
echo htmlentities($template);

?>
```